# How to co-install libpython3.5 with libpython3.6 and libpython3.7

Tags: drivers, python, udev

My employer recently purchased a CamBoard pico flexx infrared camera, and now I need to install the drivers for it on my machine.

Eventually I plan to use this with python and opencv2, so naturally I started looking at the python installation instructions where it specifies the following:

> ### Linux installation
>
> On Ubuntu and Debian, install python3-matplotlib and its dependencies.
>
> You also need the libpython3.x package for the same minor version of
>   python3.x that the roypy library was built for. In Debian and Ubuntu
>   the libpython3.5, libpython3.6 and libpython3.7 libraries are all
>   co-installable. For example, if running a sample fails with:
>
> ```
> ImportError: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> ```
>
> then the libpython3.5 package is required.

I have python 3.6.7 installed on my system along with libpython3.6, which I figured would work, but when I ran roypy.py, it still returns the same the above import error, but when I use

```
apt install libpython3.5
```

I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libpython3.5-stdlib' for regex 'libpython3.5'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.5-minimal' for regex 'libpython3.5'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So how do I co-install libpython3.5 alongside libpython3.6?

Here is a link to the driver I need to install: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1URsXZYvZnm6GHiCgMOFORyeOWIu0chH9

To install the driver, you need to navigate to ./driver/udev/ and do the following:

> If you are using ubuntu, copy the .rules file to /etc/udev/rules.d/ to
>   use pmd devices without administrative privileges (you will need root
>   rights once to copy the file to the destination):
>
> sudo cp 10-royale-ubuntu.rules /etc/udev/rules.d
>
> Please make sure that the user is in the group plugdev!
>
> After copying the udev rule, please unplug and reinsert the camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. I managed to solve this by building and installing Python 3.5.7 from source:

First, download and unpack python 3.5.7:

```
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.7/Python-3.5.7.tgz
$ tar zxvf Python-3.5.7.tgz
$ cd Python-3.5.7
```

Next, configure the package with `--enable-shared` option which installs the needed shared library file, including `libpython3.5m.so.1.0` and other necessary files. `--enable-optimizations` is optional.

```
$ ./configure --enable-shared --enable-optimizations
```

Then make with `altinstall` option which ensures 3.5.7 won't overwrite your main python installation.

```
$ make
$ sudo make altinstall
```

The final step is to load the shared library:

```
$ ldconfig
```

Full commands:

```
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.7/Python-3.5.7.tgz
$ tar zxvf Python-3.5.7.tgz
$ cd Python-3.5.7
$ ./configure --enable-shared --enable-optimizations
$ make
$ sudo make altinstall
$ sudo ldconfig
```